# VS Code how to use github with existing local project

Tags: github

I have a local project in C:\ABC folder, just realize it's time to back it up to GitHub. This is what I did:

1. Log on to GitHub, created a new project (repository or whatever you
   can call).
2. Copy the URL.
3. Back to VS Code, install GitHub extension.
4. Go Welcome page, click on "Clone Git repository...". Paste the URL
   for "Repository URL". Enter my local path C:\ABC, .

> Error Git: fatal: destination path "C:\ABC" already exists and is not
> an empty directory.

I understand it tried to fetch from GitHub to local, but what I want is the opposite. Googled found many articles and video on how to do from scratch, but not for existing local project.

**Update of 2021-08**,

see [my latest step-by-step solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452694/5063031)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try instead with command-line:

```
cd c:\ABC
git init .
git config --global user.name <yourGitHubAccount>
git config --global user.email <yourGitHubEmailAccount>
git add .

git status
# edit .gitignore to ignore folder you don't want

git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/<yourGitHubAccount>/<yourRepo.git>
git push -u origin master
```

Make sure your GitHub repo was actually empty (no `README.md`)

Comment: @VoC I got
`On branch master
Initial commit
Untracked files: .gitignore .vscode/ Angular/ ... server.js`

Comment: bottom screen says `"nothing added to commit but untracked files present"`

Comment: @Jeb50 When do you have those messages? After typing which command?

Comment: Yes. Not able to add into comment.

Comment: the err is from `git commit -m "first commit"`.

Answer (score 5):

@VonC, re-did the same steps:
1) create a new local empty directory, in VS Code link local empty directory to the empty repository at GitHub as described. Succeeded.

2) populate this local empty directory with my code files/directories.

3) `git init .`
system msg: Reinitialized existing Git repository .../.git/

3) ran these two commands one at a time, no error nor message.

```
git config --global user.name Jeb50 
git config --global user.email Jeb50@XYZ.com
```

4) `git add .` 
System msg:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .vscode/launch.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Angular/Modules/mainApp.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in content/Site.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

5) `git status`
System msg:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   .vscode/launch.json
        new file:   Angular/Controllers/AuthController.js
        new file:   Angular/Controllers/MainController.js
        new file:   Angular/Models/user.js
        new file:   Angular/Modules/mainApp.js
        new file:   Passport/passport-init.js
        new file:   Routes/authentication.js
        new file:   Routes/routerMEAN2.js
        new file:   Untitled.png
        new file:   Views/Authentication/login.html
        new file:   Views/Authentication/register.html
        new file:   Views/Authentication/unauth.html
        new file:   Views/Main/About.html
        new file:   Views/Main/Contact.html
        new file:   Views/Main/index.html
        new file:   Views/Starter.ejs
        new file:   content/Site.css
        new file:   package-lock.json
        new file:   package.json
        new file:   server.js
```

6) my .gitignore file:

```
# individual files
9222.jpg
err1.jpg
config.js

# exclude  folders
node_modules/
```

7) `git commit -m "first commit"`, seems ok but no code shown under the repository
System msg:

```
[master (root-commit) f8e435e] first commit
 21 files changed, 2305 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 .vscode/launch.json
 create mode 100644 Angular/Controllers/AuthController.js
 create mode 100644 Angular/Controllers/MainController.js
 create mode 100644 Angular/Models/user.js
 create mode 100644 Angular/Modules/mainApp.js
 create mode 100644 Passport/passport-init.js
 create mode 100644 Routes/authentication.js
 create mode 100644 Routes/routerMEAN2.js
 create mode 100644 Untitled.png
 create mode 100644 Views/Authentication/login.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Authentication/register.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Authentication/unauth.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Main/About.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Main/Contact.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Main/index.html
 create mode 100644 Views/Starter.ejs
 create mode 100644 content/Site.css
 create mode 100644 package-lock.json
 create mode 100644 package.json
 create mode 100644 server.js
```

8) `git remote add origin https://github.com/Jeb50/MEAN2.git`
System msg:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

9) `git push -u origin master`
System msg:

```
Counting objects: 34, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 30.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To https://github.com/TLKG/MEAN2.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Refresh Code tab at GitHub, expected files show up. Seems working.

> Awesome!

Comment: Just found out. There is also another way to do it. 1) download and install GitHub Desktop (v 0.8.0).  2) Sign in using this app to connect to GitHub.  3) File, Add local repository...  .Haven't got a chance, hope Desktop will work. GitHub is great w/ some confusion, good thing is spending some time learn something new.

Answer (score 5):

I was just able to do this using github desktop app with three clicks:  https://help.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop

**The key direction is this: You can add any Git repository to GitHub Desktop, *even if it's not a GitHub repository*.**

It will recognize that the directory is not a repo and ask if you want to create one instead.  [image: screenshot of what to click to create repo]

**After clicking create repo you'll be presented with this:**

[image: full repo create dialogue]

**And finally, it will even prompt you to publish it to Github for backup:**

[image: publish to github]

Answer (score 1):

This solution may be lame but worked like a charm for me.

1) Log on to GitHub, create a repository with a similar as your project.
2) Copy the URL.
3) Open VS Code clone the repository to local use. 
  This you can do by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, which will    open an input box.
    Write clone in the input box and select clone.
    Paste the git repository url and select any empty directory to clone.
4) Open your local project, copy and paste every thing except .git folder to the cloned repository.
5) Now open the new cloned project in VS Code.
6) Go to View > SCM 
7) Enter some comment(something like initial commit) in the input.
8) click the check icon, select yes and enter some message.
9) click on option of SCM( three dots besides the check button) and publish the branch.

Comment: It Worked. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I did adding an existing folder/project from VSCode into GitHub using SourceTree:

1. Create a repo on GitHub. Upon creation you can have a .gitignore created or do this manually in Step 3.
2. From the root of the project at the command line type the following to initialize this project as a Git repo: `git init`
3. Create a .gitignore for your particular project manually in the root (if not already created in your repo from Step 1), making sure to ignore all pertinent files (i.e. node_modules for web projects). It's best to copy a completed on from an existing template in Github (https://github.com/github/gitignore)
4. Open SourceTree and press 'Clone/New'
5. Select the 'Add Working Copy Tab'
6. In the 'Working Copy Path' use the ellipses to locate the root directory where the Git project was initialized in Step #1. You'll know you did it correctly because next to 'Repository Type' in the dialog, you should see a message that states, "This is a Git repository." Close the dialog.
7. Go to the 'Settings' in the top-right and 'Add' a remote.
8. Assuming default settings, the 'Name' is 'origin' (select 'Default remote'), and for URL / Path enter the full GitHub path provided when you created the repo in Step 1. Press OK. (i.e. `https://github.com/MyUserName/MyCoolCode.git`)
9. Stage and commit your files
10. Push the master branch to 'origin'

I'll admit, I think the command line instructions provided by GitHub to initialize the repo and do your 1st commit are easier. However, at this point your GitHub repo is all wired up correctly in SourceTree and you are good to go.

I'll also say, if you can think ahead it's a lot easier to create an empty repo and clone it in SourceTree before doing any work. This is for sure the easiest to get tracking from day 1. However, the steps above will work well for adding an existing solution.