# How to add a new project to Github using VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

All the tutorials i've seen till now shows to first create a repository on github, copy the link go to vscode and `git clone` it and from that on, you can do commits and pushes.

Is that the right way ? can't I just start a project from vscode and then upload it to my git ?

### EDIT 2020 :

You can now do it right inside vscode! just follow these steps:

1- Open your new project folder with vscode

2- click on the source conrol menu on the sidebar [image] (or press Ctrl+Shift+G)

3- Click on publish to github [image]

4- From there just login and follow the instructions and you're good to go.

@Debu's answer details every step, so you can [jump to there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898638/2429678)

Comment: that is the right way. and easy to do using GUI.

Comment: But its less convenient... IMO

Comment: What do you mean by "Star"?

Comment: @ifconfig am sorry that was a typo i meant "start" i corrected it

Comment: You can use the command palette Ctrl+Shift+P and search there for publish to Github.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, It's quite easy.

Open your local project.

---

> [image: VSCode source control interface showing Open Folder and CLone Repository]

---

Add a `README.md` file (If you don't have anything else to add yet)

---

> [image: VSCode explorer interface showing README.md]

---

Click on `Publish on Github`

---

> [image: VSCode source control interface showing Initialize Repository and Clone to GitHub]

---

Choose whether you want your repo to be private or public

---

> [image: Interface showing choice between private and public repos]

---

Choose the files you want to include in first commit.
Note: If you don't select a file or folder it will added to `.gitignore` file

---

> [image: Showing interface where you choose which files to include in the repo]

---

You are good to go. it is published.

P.S. If this was your first time a prompt will ask for for your Github Credentials. Fill those in and you are good to go. It is published.

Comment: When to choose initialize repository and when to choose publish to github ?

Comment: Initializing Repository will create a `.git` folder inside the local repo, which will help you manage code using git file system. But, please note you have this code in your local, not on the cloud. So if your system crashes everything vanishes.

But to deal with that situation you can publish the repo to GitHub. Everything will be the same as above but now you have the code on the cloud.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P, Type Publish to GitHub.

Comment: Worked great, just needed the "GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension". for that just type on browser vscode:extension/GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github

Comment: @GiridharanVenkatapathy yep already have it. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to publish it to an Organisation in my Github account rather than just my personal account? In Github I am a member of an organisation but when I get to the "Choose whether you want your repo to be private or public" it only lists options for my personal account, not the organisation.

Comment: @StephenGraham Yes it is possible, you can log in with your org account in VS Code and it should give you the option to publish in that account as a private or public repo.

Answer (score 196):

Here are the detailed steps needed to achieve this.

The existing commands can be simply run via the CLI terminal of VS-CODE. It is understood that Git is installed in the system, configured with desired username and email Id.

1. Navigate to the local project directory and create a local git repository:

   `git init`
2. Once that is successful, click on the 'Source Control' icon on the left navbar in VS-Code.One should be able to see files ready to be commit-ed. Press on 'Commit' button, provide comments, stage the changes and commit the files. Alternatively you can run from CLI

   `git commit -am "Your comment"`
3. Now you need to visit your GitHub account and create a new Repository. Exclude creating 'README.md', '.gitIgnore' files. Also do not add any License to the repo. Sometimes these settings cause issue while pushing in.
4. Copy the link to this newly created GitHub Repository.
5. Come back to the terminal in VS-CODE and type these commands in succession:

   `git remote add origin <Link to GitHub Repo>`     //maps the remote repo link to local git repo

   `git remote -v`                                  //this is to verify the link to the remote repo

   `git push -u origin master`                      // pushes the commit-ed changes into the remote repo

> Note: If it is the first time the local git account is trying to
> connect to GitHub, you may be required to enter credentials to GitHub in a separate window.

6. You can see the success message in the Terminal.  You can also verify by refreshing the GitHub repo online.

Comment: is it possible to make a vscode extension that does all these commands  ?

Comment: @VikramK thanks  for your answer it is clearly useful to many people. but this is not exactly what i wanted. these are commands and can be run from any other terminal than the one vscode has. I was expecting a GUI way of doing it, you know the same way you do commits in vs-code with the git extension. So I was thinking about the possibility to create th repo from vscode(not the integrated terminal). Hope I make sense...

Comment: @Xsmael you could have mentioned that in the question title clearly then..However I'll look into this as well

Comment: I had to use --force in the push command because I selected a LICENSE on GitHub while creating the new repo and my local Git refused to merge the changes.

Comment: Is there advantage to this method versus just clicking on the Publish to Github button that VSCode provides which they will make a repo on github for you?

Comment: don't miss git add. between step 1 & step 2

Answer (score 52):

This feature was added in [1.45](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_45), demoed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_45/publish-repository.gif).

Launch the command palette `Ctrl+Shift+P`, run `Publish to Github`, and follow the prompt. You will be given the choice between a private and public repository, so be careful that you choose the right one.

[image: running from command palette]

It may ask you to login to github. It will then prompt for the repo name (defaults to the name of the folder), and for creating a .gitignore file (defaults to empty .gitignore). Just hit enter if you are fine with the defaults. When you are done it should give you a popup notification in the bottom right with a link to the repo `https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>`

*Minor warning: if your project already has a .gitignore file in it this process will overwrite it*

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. Specifically adding a new project to github without leaving the Visual Studio Code interface.

Comment: This should be the actual, correct answer to the actual question. I understand this feature didn't always exist but I feel like this is what the original poster was looking for rather than all of the command line answers.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Besides, it is simple and straight forward

Comment: Yes. This should be marked as Answer. Earlier when project was created I will delete .git folder and then open VS Code. Then only I will get the "Initialize the repository" & "Publish To GitHub" options. Now with "Ctrl+Shift+P" and then "Publish to Github" we can achieve the OP required functionality

Answer (score 22):

Install git on your PC and setup configuration values in either Command Prompt (cmd) or VS Code terminal (`` Ctrl + ` ``)

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email youremail@domain.com
```

Setup editor

Windows eg.:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession"
```

Linux / Mac eg.:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Check git settings which displays configuration details

```
git config --list
```

Login to github and create a remote repository. Copy the URL of this repository

Navigate to your project directory and execute the below commands

```
git init                                                           // start tracking current directory
git add -A                                                         // add all files in current directory to staging area, making them available for commit
git commit -m "commit message"                                     // commit your changes
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo-name.git    // add remote repository URL which contains the required details
git pull origin master                                             // always pull from remote before pushing
git push -u origin master                                          // publish changes to your remote repository
```

Answer (score 12):

today is **2020-12-25**, my VSC is **1.52.1**, tried all above not very successful. Here is complete steps I did to add my existing local project to GitHub using VSC (Note: Do not create a corresponding repository at GitHub):

1. [Install the GibHub extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github) to VSC.
2. Close and re-open VSC.
3. Sign in to GibHub if prompted.
4. Open my own local folder, up to this moment, it's not pushed to GibHub yet.
5. F1, click on **Publish to GitHub** (or type in if not prompted).

[image]

6. You will be provided a choice of adding it as **private** or **public**, so make up a name for your to-be new repository in this format: `<your username>/<your new repository name>`. For example, my username is "myname" and my local folder is named "HelloWorld". it will be `myname/HelloWorld` in the type-in box.
7. update or accept this name, click on the private or public choice will Create a new repository at GitHub and Publish your folder to it.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Push code on git hub in V S code**

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m " test this app"

git remote add origin https://github.com/username/flutterapp.git

git push or 

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new GitHub repository.
2. Go to the command line in VS code (ctrl+`).
3. Type following commands:

   ```
   git init
   git commit -m "first commit"
   git remote add origin https://github.com/userName/repoName.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I think I ran into the similar problem. If you started a local git repository but have not set up a remote git project and want to push your local project to to git project.

1) create a remote git project and note the URL of project

2) open/edit your local git project

3) in the VS terminal type: git push --set-upstream [URL of project]

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice GUI way to do this. Press CTRL+SHIFT+G ( or View-CSM in menu) and here you have a lot of options. With (...) you can do almost anything you want. After things be done, type your commit message into input box and press CTRL+ENTER. Pretty easy.
If you have remote repo - you'll see a little spinner mark in bottom left corner near repo name. Press it and sync to remote easily.
But in order to do all of this you must have repo to be initialized in your working directory before (`git init` from terminal).

Comment: you didnt bring in anythin new

Comment: fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can upload your git repo from vs code. You have to get in the projects working directory and type git init in the terminal. Then add the files to your repository like you do with regular git commits.

Comment: while, this works, its not really from vs code as you mentioned.

Comment: Its just a git command which is run on terminal. As vs code allows you to access the terminal from the editor itself, you don't have to switch between tabs.

Comment: okay, so there is no "GUI-way" to do it like for the `commit` or `push` in vs code

Answer (score 2):

Go to VS COde -> View -> Terminal

[image]

git init
git add .
git commit -m "FirstCommit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/dotnetpiper/cdn
git pull origin master
git push -f origin master

Note : Some time git push -u origin master doesn't work anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use command palette:

1. (CTRL+SHIFT+P - Win) or (CMD+SHIFT+P - Mac) to open the palette.
2. Enter 'git', select Git:Clone,
3. paste github repo URL (https://github.com/Username/repo),
4. than you are ready to go with Source control section from the left
       menu.

Does the same thing as the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a GitHub repo via the command line using the GitHub API.
Outside of the API, there's no way to create a repo on GitHub via the command line.

Type:

curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"projectname","description":"project desc"}'

git remote add origin git@github.com:nyeates/projectname.git

and now you can continue regular way

Answer (score 1):

Here are the commands you can use to add a new project to GitHub using VS Code:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <repository URL>
git push -u origin master
```

If you face any issue like fatal: repository not found, check your repository url and check whether you are authenticated.

Note: You should run these commands from the terminal within VS Code and make sure you are in the correct directory of your project. And also you need to make sure that you are authenticated before running the last command.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below steps to add or export an existing project to GitHub and it should work for all the environments.

1. Create a new Repo in GitHub then copy the repo URL
2. Open the terminal in VS or Gitbash
3. You should be in the project path / working directory
4. **git init**         //to initialize git on local directory
5. **git add .**        // add your project
6. **git commit -m *"YOUR MESSAGE"***
7. **git remote add origin**
8. **git remote -v**
9. **git push -f origin master**    // to push your changes to Git repo

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the steps from `VS CODE` only:

1. Open command pallet (cmd+shift+p), do `git initialized repository`.
2. Open command pallet (cmd+shift+p), do `git add and commit`.
3. Open command pallet (cmd+shift+p), do `git add remote`, then you will have a screen like this, do the click as mentioned:

   [image]

   You will have all the repository available on your GitHub account, this would help you add remote from vs code only, considering repository is already present on your GitHub account.
4. Open command pallet (cmd+shift+p), do `git push`, it would ask you for private or publish repository choose whatever you like.

> We could have used the terminal from vscode as mentioned by others but
> I find more intuitive doing this way.

Note - VS code would ask you in-between to authorized your vscode for your GitHub account uses.

Answer (score -2):

What should you do, delete .git folder from your app/ folder
delete large files or move somewhere else, in my case I don't need it.
then git init again

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. It starts like a question instead of an answer, then changes to seeming a description of your problem. It also suffers from lack of helpful formatting. (See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.